# SourceTree not staging all files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a web application I'm moving from SVN to git and when I place the files/folders into my new repository folder I only get 2773 of 3897 files to be staged. I even tried chunking the stage process but I still end up with the same result.

I'm a new to git and I setup a new repository for this application in BitBucket using Gitflow. I haven't changed any defaults or anything but I'm concerned not all of my files are making it through. Is there some setting I need to change for this?

Comment: @janos They don't even appear in the File Status window under Unstaged Files. I just did a git status --ignore and a bunch of stuff came up. What gives?

Comment: @janos there's over a thousand files missing. I can specifically see two files in the root of my repo that didn't appear as unstaged when I dragged them into the folder, so I can't be confident anything actually worked.

Comment: @janos I can't even tell because it spits out 1000's of lines in the console. Even if it was, why would it be ignoring them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91264/discussion-between-ryan-and-janos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the files you consider "missing", are marked ignored.

On the command line you can see the list of files marked ignored with:

```
git status --ignored
```

Use `grep` to search in this list:

```
git status --ignored | grep some_example_name
```

Files in this list should not be staged, and it's normal that they don't show up in Source Tree as unstaged files. On the command line,
these files will not show up in a simple `git status` either.

Note that there are multiple ways to mark files as ignored.
One common way is using `.gitignore` files in the project (and put under version control).
Another is global settings,
to ignore common extensions that most probably nobody would ever want to include in their repositories by default.

In conclusion, everything seems to be normal here.